# How can I select all rows where the item id is not associated to a specific id in an associative table

Tags: sql, database, join, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have two tables, which we'll call `product` and `customer`.

I also have an associative table, `product_customer`, joining product and customer ids in a many-to-many relationship.

E.g:

```
 PRODUCT          CUSTOMER             JOIN TABLE
id | name        id | name       product_id | customer_id
----------       ----------      ------------------------
1  | apple       1  | bill       1          | 2
2  | orange      2  | bob        2          | 1
                 3  | ben        2          | 2
```

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will select *all* products that are not associated to a particular customer, e.g.

- for customer `1`, the query would return only the `orange` row, as customer `1` is associated with product 2
- for customer `2`, the query would return no rows, as customer `2` is associated with both product `1` and `2`
- for customer `3`, the query would return all rows, as customer `3` is not associated with either products

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Not sure if the particular brand of SQL is important, but I'm using a H2 database, but using a native spring-boot `@Query` annotation.

Comment: "Any help" is not a valid SO question. Please show what parts you can do. Please in code questions give a [mre]. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate all combination of customers and products.  Then use `left join`/`not exists` or a set-based operation to filter out the ones that do exist:

```
select c.name, p.name
from customer c cross join
     product p left join
     jointable jt
     on c.id = jt.customer_id and p.id = jt.product_id
where jt.customer_id is null;
```

Comment: Didn't think about doing the other way for cross join ..this is great @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful for you to give an idea, I did in SQL server and you can achieve using left join, cross join and not exists.

Not exists is needed as the cross join would not order properly and not equal to will compare row by row , so addition of not exists will eliminate that.

```
with PRODUCT as (select 1 as ID, 'Apple'as name
                  union all 
                  select 2 as ID, 'Orange'as name), 
customer as (select 1 as ID, 'bill' as name union all 
             select 2 as ID, 'bob' as name union all 
             select 3 as ID, 'ben' as name ), 
jointbl as (select 1 as Product_id, 2 as Customer_id union all  
            select 2 as Product_id, 1 as Customer_id union all  
            select 2 as Product_id, 2 as Customer_id)

select distinct  c.id as Customer_id ,c.name as Customer_name, p.name as Fruit_name, 
  p.ID as Product_id  
 from customer c 
left join jointbl j on c.ID = j.Customer_id 
cross join PRODUCT p  
where isnull(p.ID,-1) <> isnull(j.Product_id,-1) and not exists (select 1 from PRODUCT  p1 
join jointbl j1  on p1.ID = j1.Product_id 
 where p.ID = p1.id and j1.Customer_id = c.ID)
order by 1
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by first generating all possible product-customers by a cartesian join between products and customers.(prod_customer block)

After that i would compare the (prod,customer) combinations in join_table and show up only the missing ones using a left join as follows

```
with prod_customer
  as (select p.id as p_id,c.id as c_id,c.name as cust_name,p.name as prod_name
        from products p
        join customers c
          on 1=1
      )
   select pc.c_id,pc.cust_name,pc.prod_name,pc_pid
     from prod_customer pc
left join join_table jt
       on pc.p_id=jt.product_id
      and pc.c_id=jt.customer_id
    where jt.customer_id is null
```